# Konva.Transformer.getClientRect() not supported in latest version?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

I am trying to implement multi-select feature using `react-konva`. I found a [multi-select sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-multiple-selection-tgggi) where I found transformer `getClientRect()` method, but in the latest version and also in the documentation that method does not exist. I have done [some changes](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-multiple-selection-forked-3oe9w5?file=/src/index.js) in the aforementioned sample code which actually relies on transformer `getClientRect()` method and it is working fine there but with the latest version that method is returning an object with all fields of value `0`.

Is there any other way to get the size of the transformer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the `Konva.Transformer` code, I figured out `getX()`, `getY()`, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods. One can use these methods and create own `getClientRect()` method as follows,

```
function getTransformerClientRect(
  transformer: Konva.Transformer | null
): IRect {
  if (!transformer) {
    return {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    };
  }

  return {
    x: transformer.getX(),
    y: transformer.getY(),
    width: transformer.getWidth(),
    height: transformer.getHeight(),
  };
}
```